# NSDictionary available between two methods

Tags: objective-c, methods, nsdictionary

The title pretty much explains it all.

I simply have an NSDictionary initialised with a bunch of keys and values in one method, but I would like another method to be able to access it within the same class. Is this possible?

Comment: change the scope of the variable to class wide by adding for example a property...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your NSDictionary as a property (mine called 'dictionary')either in your .h or .m file. Initialise it anywhere in your code and call it with self.dictionary, goodluck!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Uhm, ever heard of such *amazing* and *totally new and never before seen* concepts such as **instance variables** and **properties**?

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary* mySharedDictionary;
```

Comment: I'm new to objective-c. A lot of this stuff is difficult to understand from documentation. Just to clarify, that goes in the header file correct? If so, where do I give it its data? Thanks :)

Comment: Actually, these *amazing* concepts can be found on almost every programming language. They are part of the object oriented programming. You can put properties in the header of in class extensions. You can fill data in `init` methods or wherever is appropriate for your software.